# Calling PHP Class from external file using namespace.

Tags: php, class, namespaces

This is my first time posting and I really wouldn't be if I wasn't out of options ( the last thing I want to be is annoying for no reason). I have been working on this script for a few days now, banging my head against the keyboard trying to figure out why its not working.

File 1: This is a partial upload class meant to be used from an external file.

```
<?php
namespace Tools\File;
class Upload {

    protected $destination;
    protected $max = 51200;
    protected $messages = array();
    protected $permitted = array('image/gif','image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png');

    public function __construct($path){
        if (!is_dir($path) || !is_writable($path)) {
            throw new \Exception ("$path must be a valid,writable directory");
        }
        $this->destination = $path;
        }
    public function upload(){
        $upload = current($_FILES);
        if ($this->checkFile($uploaded)){
            $this->moveFile($uploaded);
            }
        }

    protected function checkFile($file){
        return true;
        }
    protected function moveFile ($file) {
        $success = move_uploaded_file($file ['tmp_name'] , $this->destination . $file['name']);
            if ($success){
                $result = $file['name'] . 'was uploaded successfully';
                    $this->messages[] = $result;
            }else{
                $this->messages[] = 'Could not upload' . $file['name'];
                }
        }   
    public function getMessages(){
        return $this->messages;
        }
}
```

File 2: Form for uploading images

```
<head>
    <?php use Tools\File\Upload as FileUploader; ?>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
        // difine the path to the upload folder
        $destination = 'C:/Uploads/';
        // Include upload class
        require_once '../Tools/File/Upload.php';
    // Creates new instance of the upload class as loader
    try{
        $loader = new FileUploader ($destination);
        $loader->getMessages();
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessages();
        }
    }   
    // Checks and echos result
        if(isset($result)){
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach($result as $message){
                echo "<li>$message</li>";
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
        ?>
<form id="uploadImage" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="image">Upload Image</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?= $max; ?>">
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image">

    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload" id="uplaod">
    </p>
</form>
<!-- For checking the Files Super global-->

<pre>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['upload'])){ print_r($_FILES);}?>
</pre>

</body>
```

The form works fine. The files are uploaded perfectly when the "move_uploaded_file" function is called inside the File 2 itself, but it doesn't seem to be calling the class at all.

I have lost count of the amount of times I have been over the code. Rearranging and Trying just about everything I know to get it to work.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. 
Thanks in advance for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the upload method from the 2nd file.  Otherwise it will instantiate the Upload class but not trigger any upload activity.

```
try {
    $loader = new FileUploader ($destination);
    $loader->upload();
    $loader->getMessages();
 } catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessages();
 }
```

Comment: For anyone looking for answers to a similar question and is looking to test this code. I had to change $uploaded to $upload in File 1, and can I just say thanks again to Steve E. I know I said I wouldn't be annoying, but I really appreciate the help

Comment: Accept the answer then :)